# Getting Playstation 2 dualport usb adapter to work in Windosw 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, drivers, playstation

I have a: Play.com USB Dual PS2 to PC Converter XP made by Joytech

It is pretty old and the driver CD is for XP. It sometimes works in 32-bit with EMS 32-bit Vista beta drivers.

Back to 64-bit:

The gamepads are not shown in the game controllers dialog. They work when programming using the SDL library as well as in an old game from 1999 called Re-Volt. I have downloaded the Windows Driver Development kit but find the documentation regarding game controllers lacking so far.

Are there any good resources on the net for writing such a driver?

Comment: Maybe better on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It is corssposted, considering the signing requirements of 64-bit I will probably not purssue it considering I have both 32-bit and 64-bit installed.

Comment: Please don't crosspost like that in the future; there are very few situations where it's really a good idea.  99.9% of the time, the question is best suited to one and only one site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably have no documentation on the protocol the converter uses -- manufacturers practically never release that sort of thing -- you're looking at a very difficult task. Unless you're after an "educational" (read: incredibly frustrating) experience, your best bet will be to just buy a new converter which is better supported by current OSes.

If you want to take it on anyway, though, your first step will probably be to get a logic analyzer and read up on how USB works. Good luck... you'll need it.

Comment: Helped me give up on 64-bit when using these and this is why I also have 32-bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded to Windows 64; for a sec you had me worried I could no longer use my adapter + controllers! **Before writing drivers, try the latest drivers from the Mayflash web site (in case Play.com/Joytech is just an OEM/rebranding...)**

- I [identified](http://www.mayflash.com/pc.htm) my adapter as  [PC013 (Super Dual Box)](http://www.mayflash.com/pc/pc013/pc013-3.htm)
- Then I downloaded the latest drivers (Oct 2009) from the [download page](http://www.mayflash.com/Download.htm)

I am running Windows 7 64 Ultimate. Both my PS controllers are identified as "Dual USB Force Feedback Joypad (MP-8866)" in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers. The "Properties" button brings up the custom Mayflash dialog; all buttons, sticks, lights, and force feedback seem to be working.